# When do fcm refresh tokens created

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to android and now looking on firebase.In my app multiple mobile numbers can be logged in. So what am doing is deleting current token by

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
```

and after that when I log in with new number, then new token gets generated.

So my question in this exactly which event triggers token regeneration event. One more thing that above code line should I have to run on thread (other than MAIN THREAD) to work

Comment: AFAIK firebase doesn't regenerate token after a token is generated. That was the case with gcm.

Comment: But in my case am deleting that id right, then only its regenerating token

Comment: it is creating token when you are logging in and the token will remain same until you delete it

Comment: ya thats what am saying when I delete then logged in its getting regenerated. My question is in this exactly which event triggers that regeration

Answer (score 3):

This is the service which I used for getting firebase token

```
    public class FCMInstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
AppSharedPreferences appSharedPreferences;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String CurrentToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (CurrentToken!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent("device_id");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            Log.d("token", "Refreshed token: " + CurrentToken);
            appSharedPreferences.putString("device_id",CurrentToken);
        }
        else {
               onTokenRefresh();
                }
       }

    public FCMInstanceIDListenerService() {

        appSharedPreferences=AppSharedPreferences.getsharedprefInstance(this);
        // prefManager = PrefManager.getInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Intent intent = new Intent("device_id");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        Log.d("token", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        appSharedPreferences.putString("device_id",refreshedToken);
        // prefManager.putString(PrefrenceConstants.KEY_DEVICE_ID, refreshedToken);

    }

}
```

From [developer site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService.html#onTokenRefresh()):

> onTokenRefresh() Called when the system determines that the tokens
>   need to be refreshed. The application should call getToken() and send
>   the tokens to all application servers.
>
> This will not be called very frequently, it is needed for key rotation
>   and to handle Instance ID changes due to:
>
> - App deletes Instance ID
> - App is restored on a new device
> - User uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - User clears app data
>
> The system will throttle the refresh event across all devices to avoid
>   overloading application servers with token updates.

Comment: what does this means "when the system determines that the tokens need to be refreshed.". Means how system determines

Comment: Why are you calling `onTokenRefresh` if `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` returned `null`, I am asking since then you will be calling it again and getting again `null`